# Load a class from a JAR implementing interface existing in my project's source code

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader, classnotfoundexception, classcastexception

One of my web application's module has a `GeneralOperation` interface that I want other users to implement in order to provide their own functionality.

I create a JAR of the module that contains this interface, and provide it to users. Then, a user can import this library and create a class `MyCustomOperation`implementing this interface. Finally, they generate a JAR that contains their implementation, and they drop their JAR in the tomcat/lib folder, so that JVM can see that during runtime.

Back to my application when I try to load their `MyCustomOperation` class, it fails to be casted to the `GeneralOperation` interface existing in the source code, because it thinks that the `GeneralOperation` that the `MyCustomOperation` implements, is a difference interface, and not the existing one.

How to resolve this?

Comment: can you post the exception trace?

Comment: The actual exception is: "**java.lang.ClassCastException**: com.example.custom.MyCustomOperation cannot be cast to com.package.api.GeneralOperation"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class is identified by its name and its class loader. your implementation `MyCustomOperation` is loaded by tomcat common class loader and Interface `GeneralOperation` is loaded by tomcat Webapp class loader. Therefore you cannot cast between these two types.

To solve your issue,

1.you can use Serialization

2.or take you Interface in to tomcat common classloder(tomcal/lib) and 
   implementation into webapp( this way you can load the class 
     without reflection).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The solution that I applied was to add the `GeneralOperation` interface in a JAR, which I import from the tomcat/lib folder. As a result, both `MyCustomOperation` and `GeneralOperation` classes are loaded by the same class loader (tomcat class loader) .